# Home app: cast my screen without all the confirmation steps

Tags: android-tv, chromecast, screencast, screen-mirroring, google-home

[image]

I find the [Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en&gl=US) app the simplest and hassle-free way to mirror phone screen to a videoprojector or tv running Android tv, and the screen-mirroring the simplest way when casting video from a phone (given the limitations of casting directly from a video player, namely subtitles etc).

But I use this very often, devices are all connected to the same wifi, I expect it to start
with one click, and avoid all the confirmation steps I see each time. After opening the app (1st click), selecting "Devices" (2nd click) and then my device (3rd click), another 3 more clicks are needed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

6 in total!

Can that be changed?

---

As you may have suspected, my Samsung lacks the quick settings (drawer) button for casting.

Comment: I don't know if it's available on your device or not, but have you checked the customization of Quick Settings tiles? I found "Screen Cast" on my Pixel 3a, Android 12. Granted, it's probably not from Google Home, but by built-in Android Cast settings.

Comment: @AndrewT. - As you may have suspected,  my Samsung lacks that button. When that is present,  it's among the default ones.  When absent,  it cannot be added at all.

Comment: @AndrewT. -Oddly, it seems that long-pressing the home button should also show a cast option, or it [used to](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/cast-your-androids-screen-2-seconds-flat-0202374/). Not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on Google play store for apps that would add a desktop/home cast icon/shortcut, I have found the [Cast Menu Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techrcs.castwidget).

In order to get the quick settings button, the (under 1 euro) paid version of the above tool can be used - or, as said [here](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/add-google-cast-button-your-quick-settings-tiles-any-phone-no-root-needed-0181286/), one can install [Nugat/Oreo Quick Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles).

Both buttons (1st click) will first show the list of available devices (2nd click to select one), then the last confirmation option, "Start now" (3rd and last click).